# How to find the distance to next non-NaN value in numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the following array:

```
arr = np.array(
    [
        [10, np.nan],
        [20, np.nan],
        [np.nan, 50],
        [15, 20],
        [np.nan, 30],
        [np.nan, np.nan],
        [10, np.nan],
        
    ]
)
```

For every cell in each column in `arr` I need to find the distance to the next non-NaN value.
That is, the expected outcome should look like this:

```
expected = np.array(
    [
        [1, 2],
        [2, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [3, 1],
        [2, np.nan],
        [1, np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan]
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can compute a reverse [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html), with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
out = (pd.DataFrame(arr).notna()[::-1]
         .apply(lambda s: s.groupby(s.cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
                           .where(s.cummax()).shift()[::-1])
         .to_numpy()
      )
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  1.],
       [ 2., nan],
       [ 1., nan],
       [nan, nan]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get some perf speedup, with a combination of binary search and some numpy functions:

```py
box = []
for num in range(arr.shape[-1]):
    temp=arr[:, num]
    # this section gets the non-nan positions
    bools = ~np.isnan(temp)
    bools = bools.nonzero()[0]
    # this section gets positions of all indices 
    # with respect to the non-nan positions
    # note the use of side='right' to get the closest non-nan position
    positions = np.arange(temp.size)
    bool_positions = bools.searchsorted(positions, side='right')
    # out of bound positions are replaced with nan
    filtered=bool_positions!=bools.size
    blanks=np.empty(temp.size, dtype=float)
    blanks[~filtered]=np.nan
    trimmed=bool_positions[filtered]
    indexer = positions[filtered]
    # subtract position of next non-nan from actual position
    blanks[indexer] = bools[trimmed] - indexer
    box.append(blanks)

np.column_stack(box)
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  1.],
       [ 2., nan],
       [ 1., nan],
       [nan, nan]])
```